# Looping through an interval in either direction

Tags: python, loops, intervals

Suppose you want to loop through all integers between two bounds `a` and `b` (inclusive), but don't know in advance how `a` compares to `b`. Expected behavior:

```
def run(a, b):
    if a < b:
        for i in range(a, b + 1):
            print i,
    elif a > b:
        for i in range(a, b - 1, -1):
            print i,
    else:
        print a
    print

run(3, 6)
run(6, 3)
run(5, 5)
```

Result:

```
3 4 5 6
6 5 4 3
5
```

Is there a more elegant solution? The following is more concise, but fails when `a == b`:

```
def run(a, b):
    for i in range(a, b + cmp(b, a), cmp(b, a)):
        print i,
    print

run(3, 6)
run(6, 3)
run(5, 5)
```

Result:

```
3 4 5 6
6 5 4 3
(...)
ValueError: range() step argument must not be zero
```

Comment: `for i in range(min((a,b)), max((a,b)) + 1)` would be the most obvious way

Comment: @TemporalWolf This gives `3 4 5 6` twice.

Comment: Yeah, I made the poor assumption you wanted them to be ascending.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work for all cases:

```
def run(a, b):
    """Iterate from a to b (inclusive)."""
    step = -1 if b < a else 1
    for x in xrange(a, b + step, step):
        yield x
```

The insight that led me to this formulation was that `step` and the adjustment to `b` were the same in both of your cases; once you have an inclusive end you don't need to special-case `a == b`. Note that I've written it as a generator so that it doesn't just `print` the results, which makes it more use when you need to integrate it with other code:

```
>>> list(run(3, 6))
[3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(run(6, 3))
[6, 5, 4, 3]
>>> list(run(5, 5))
[5]
```

---

Using generator delegation in Python 3.3+ (see [PEP-380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/)), this becomes even neater:

```
def run(a, b):
    """Iterate from a to b (inclusive)."""
    step = -1 if b < a else 1
    yield from range(a, b + step, step)
```

Comment: Yes. Or, in a terser way: `range(a, b + 2 * int(a < b) - 1, 2 * int(a < b) - 1)`. I'm curious if there is a better solution than yours.

Comment: @Aristide `2 * int(a < b) - 1` is exactly the same length as `-1 if b < a else 1`, and I would argue that the latter is significantly more readable.

Comment: Haha, what about `(a < b) or - 1` Even shorter, even more cryptic, but satisfies the test cases.

Comment: @jonrsharpe good call... and slightly less cryptic :) Yikes... don't even need the parentheses: PyCharm happily takes `for i in range(a, b + (a < b or -1), (a < b or -1)):`

Comment: I _really_ wanted to dream up some nice purely mathematical way to get the sign and step at once, but I think this as good as it gets :)

Comment: @TemporalWolf you don't even need the parens around the `step`, you only need them in `end` because [`+` binds more tightly than `<` and `or`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: @jonrsharpe That being said, this is still less readable than your original suggestion, which makes it clear what the step will be without having to know how python's booleans work.

Comment: Now, this is real fun! And a tradeoff between @jonrsharpe and @TemporalWolf solutions would be: `step = a < b or -1`.

Comment: `def run(a, b): print ' '.join([str(i) for i in xrange(a, b + ((a < b) or - 1), (a < b) or - 1)])` as a list comprehension for the entire function :) All things aside, personally, the answer given by @jonrsharpe is better, as it's clear what the step is being set to, even if it is a few characters longer.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it yourself:

```
def run(a, b):
    for i in range(a, b + (cmp(b, a) or 1), cmp(b, a) or 1):
        print i,
    print
```

works just fine... when `cmp(b, a)` evaluates to `0` (when they are equal), it defaults to `1`, although I'd definitely consider Jon's answer more elegant, you were on the right track! I make extensive use of python's logical `or` when doing comparisons like this:

`(func() or default)` is very useful for any function that returns a zero that you want to overwrite. Python evaluates it as `False or True` and returns `default`.

Answer (score -3):

```
range(min((a,b)), max((a,b))+1)
```